# Remove NodePort from existing service using helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have deployed the kubernetes cluster using helm chart. There are LoadBalancers which expose NodePort but now we want to remove or disable NodePort.

We found a reference (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#load-balancer-nodeport-allocation ) which explains about disabling NodePort allocation but there is a constraint that

> If spec.allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts is set to false on an existing Service with allocated node ports, those node ports will not be de-allocated automatically. You must explicitly remove the nodePorts entry in every Service port to de-allocate those node ports.

I am looking for a way to remove NodePort from existing service using helm chart instead of editing individual services.

Could someone help me with any possible efficient approach to solve the problem.

Comment: What does your current chart look like?  My understanding is that, under the hood, Kubernetes normally expects a LoadBalancer to be an external object that points at a NodePort port, so you can't have a LoadBalancer without also having a NodePort.  Depending on how your chart creates its Service, you might be able to downgrade a LoadBalancer Service to a ClusterIP Service via `helm upgrade` with appropriate values.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. Your answer sounds reasonable. I will check further. But I have doubt, I hope that there won't be any traffic failure during this downgrade process. Am I correct?